# Force connection on specific USB port/symlink

Tags: c, linux-kernel, usb

I am planning to use Dump1090 and I want to have 2 RTLSDR dongles on the same computer, always plugged into the same USB port. I am planning to assign a symlink "adsb" to the port for the RTL dongle that has an ADS-B antenna connected to it. Is there a way to force the connection on this specific USB port?

By default, the code takes the first device available.

Thank you

https://github.com/antirez/dump1090/blob/master/dump1090.c

Comment: "Port" can be a pretty flaky concept at best due to how the USB bus can be extended with hubs.

Comment: I've seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters) that you can distinguish a specific USB port as follows: "The name given to this device by the kernel (KERNELS=="1-4.5") indicates that this device is plugged into the fifth port of a hub connected to port four on bus 1". I'm just not sure where I would tell the program to use a specific port instead of looking for a product ID.

Comment: Also, the computer I am using only has 1 USB bus with 4 ports. The devices will always get plugged into the same ports (in fact, they will always stay plugged in).